# Puppeteer "error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: moduleRaid2 is not defined"

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer, bun

I have a problem with puppeteer when running the build application. I made an application with whatsappweb-js which requires using puppeteer.

This issue does not occur when not running on the build results. but when running the built application, I experienced an error like the one I listed below.

```
throw error;
7210 |       }
7211 |       const { exceptionDetails, result: remoteObject } = await callFunctionOnPromise.catch(rewriteError);
7212 |       if (exceptionDetails)
7213 | 
7214 |         throw new Error("Evaluation failed: " + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                 ^
error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: moduleRaid2 is not defined
    at moduleRaid (eval at <anonymous> (:2:14), <anonymous>:2:5)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:17
      at /Users/ranggaalk/Documents/Apps/CBT/foco-bot/dist/App.js:7214:14
      at processTicksAndRejections (:55:76)
```

and this is the App.ts source code before it is built to run the browser on WhatsAppweb-js

```
const client = new Client({
    puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
        args: [ '--disable-gpu', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox', '--no-zygote' ],
        executablePath: './node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-982053/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium',
     },
     takeoverOnConflict: true,
     takeoverTimeoutMs: 10,
     authStrategy,
});
```

I have tried running with local chrome but when running on the build results, the error is still the same.

whatsapp-web.js version package :
"whatsapp-web.js": "^1.23.0"

I want puppeteer to be able to run on the build results of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Found a [closed issue](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1048) from the library repo regarding the same issue you are facing.

Looking to update the package could lead to the resolution of the issue and changing chromium to chrome:

```
npm update whatsapp-web.js@latest
```